# Gitlab CI: mount Apache service Docker DocumentRoot directory into main Docker

Tags: docker, mount, gitlab-ci

On every push, gitlab-ci starts my main docker `my-deploy` and clones the code into the `/builds` directoy.

Now I have added a service docker `my-apache` to the above one. The `my-apache` docker is set up to start apache and use `/shared/httpd/localhost` as its DocumentRoot for apache.

The project-based `.gitlab-ci.yml` looks like this:

```
#
# This starts `my-deploy` docker and links an apache service docker...
#
testing:
    stage: deploy
    services:
        - my-apache:latest
    script:
        - curl $MY_APACHE_PORT_80_TCP_ADDR
```

Now I want my checked out code (inside `my-deploy` docker in directory `/builds`) to be mounted/linked into the apache docker `my-apache` into the dir `/shared/httpd/localhost`.

**The mount/link should be:**

`my-deploy:/builds` -> `my-apache:/shared/httpd/localhost`

Any idea if this is possible and how to configure this?

My gitlab-runner config (`/etc/gitlab-runner/config.toml`) which adds `my-deploy` as a runner looks like this:

```
# Main Linter
[[runners]]
  url = "https://gitlab.mydomain.com/ci"
  token = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
  name = "MY_DEPLOY"
  executor = "docker"
  limit = 0
  [runners.docker]
    image = "my-deploy:latest"
    privileged = false
    cache_dir = ""
    disable_cache = true
    wait_for_services_timeout = 90
```

**Update:**

How gitlab does the docker integration:

http://docs.gitlab.com/ce/ci/docker/using_docker_images.html#how-docker-integration-works

Answer (score 0):

The [gitlab ci doc](https://gitlab.com/wiget/gitlab-ci-multi-runner/blob/master/docs/configuration/advanced-configuration.md) includes in its [`[runners.docker]` section](https://gitlab.com/wiget/gitlab-ci-multi-runner/blob/master/docs/configuration/advanced-configuration.md#the-runnersdocker-section)

```
volumes
```

> specify additional volumes that should be mounted (same syntax as [`docker run -v` option](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#/volume-shared-filesystems): see "[Mount a shared-storage volume as a data volume¶](https://docs.docker.com/engine/tutorials/dockervolumes/#/mount-a-shared-storage-volume-as-a-data-volume)")

Make sure to define a common volume that you would mount as `/build` in `my-deploys`, and `/shared/httpd/localhost` in `my-apache`.

That would allow the data produced in `my-deploy:/build` to be visible in `my-apache:/shared/httpd/localhost`.

That means:

- first declare a docker data volume (outside of GitLab), with [`docker volume create`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/volume_create/),
- second, use that volume in your `[runners.docker]` section of your  `gitlab-ci.yml`

  ```
  volumes = ["my-named-volume:/build", "my-named-volume:/shared/httpd/localhost"]
  ```

Comment: Could you give an example please.

Comment: @lockdoc I have added docs, links, and syntax example to the answer. What I fear (as I have not tested it yet), is that you declares in volumes multiple mounting points, which means your named volume is mounted twice per service. (one in `/build`, on in `/shared/httpd/localhost`). Check it out, and see if at least your two containers do share the same volume at the expected paths.

Comment: so do I have to define `VOLUME` inside the `Dockerfile` in order to make a common directory?

Comment: @lockdoc no, this is a command (`docker volume create`) that you execute manually once (where your docker daemon is): that will persists a volume that you will be able to reuse across sessions. (`docker volume ls` can show it): https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/volume_create/

Comment: In my `/etc/gitlab-runner/config.toml` I have added `volumes = ["my-named-volume:/build", "my-named-volume:/shared/httpd/localhost"]` under the `[runners.docker]` section inside a docker.

My `my-deploy/Dockerfile` has the section `VOLUME ["/builds"]` and my `my-apache/Dockerfile` has the section `VOLUME ["/shared/httpd/localhost"]` (each at the very bottom).

The only part I am missing is how to generate the volume file and assign it to bot.

Comment: I would not declare volume in the Dockerfile itself

Comment: So I did

* `docker volume create --name my-named-volume`
* changed `/etc/gitlab-runner/config.toml`
* Removed `VOLUME` from Dockerfiles

The only thing I get is `/shared/httpd/localhost` in `my-deploy` Docker, but this directory holds exactly the same contents as `/builds` from the same docker.

I actually wanted to get `/shared/httpd/localhost` from the `my-apache` docker, mounted to `my-docker`

Comment: @lockdoc is `my-apache` also declared in `config.toml`, or is run through a `docker-compose.yml` or a `docker run` command? In those latter cases, you need to mount that same volume for that `my-apache` container. And you can modify the `config.toml` to `volumes = ["my-named-volume:/build"]` only, since `my-apache` is not affected by it (no need to mount that volume twice in `my-deploy`).

Comment: Neither of them, it is declared in `.gitlab-ci.yml`, under the `service` section. See my initial question.
In that case, do I also have to change it then?

Comment: @lockdoc the only change is to find how my-apache is launched and to mount that same named volume to it, and you will be all set.

Comment: `my-apache` is launched by gitlab-ci-multi-runner automatically, simply by adding it to the service section (see above) in `gitlab-ci.yml` (which is a project file). In the above example it is even per project, per job.
And this is actually my initial question: how to link their directories together :-)

Comment: @lockdoc for testing, could you try and launch your `my-apache` container manually (`docker run`), a bit as described with http://docs.gitlab.com/ce/ci/docker/using_docker_images.html (and with the `-v my-named-volume:/shared/httpd/localhost` option of course: that is the all point of this answer: reuse the same volume with the same content between the two containers)

Comment: I started both with ` docker run -i -v my-named-volume:/builds -t <DOCKER_NAME>` The apache one starts a foreground process, so i cannot enter it. The main docker starts interactively, but yet, nothing in `/builds` even though the apache Dockerfile had something like `echo "test" > /builds/test.txt`

Comment: @lockdoc `-v my-named-volume:/builds`? I mentioned `-v my-named-volume:/shared/httpd/localhost` for the `my-apache` container. Why did you use `/builds`?

Comment: @lockdoc `my-deploy` is correctly launched by gitlab, with `/builds` mounted, thanks to the `volumes = ["my-named-volume:/build"]` section of the `config.toml`. I am talking about `my-apache`: launch that one.

Comment: The apache docker now has content inside `/builds` as well as `/shared/httpd/localhost` so that both could work.

I have started the apache docker manually on the host which has the `gitlab-multirunner` running...
I also forced a new build on gitlab, but i don't see any changes now.
I guess gitlab starts its own instance of the apache docker.

Comment: @lockdoc can you check that "gitlab, but i don't see any changes now. I guess gitlab starts its own instance of the apache docker" with a `docker ps -a`

Comment: @lockdoc "The apache docker now has content inside /builds as well as /shared/httpd/localhost": do you mean the apache you have launched manually? That should not be the case as the *only* -v option that you have used (I hope) is `-v my-named-volume:/shared/httpd/localhost`: there is no `/builds` there.

Comment: `docker ps -a` shows a lot of docker stuff going on when gitlab-ci starts a build. Also looks like the apache docker is started.

The mentioned files are added via "my-apache/Dockerfile" directly via `echo "foo" > /builds/test.txt` and also into the `/shared/httpd/localhost/test.txt` just to check from the other docker if something is already inside this dir

Comment: This is how the docker integration works under Gitlab:

http://docs.gitlab.com/ce/ci/docker/using_docker_images.html#how-docker-integration-works

Looks like it created its own master docker, which holds them all.

Comment: @lockdoc yes, that is what I was reading before, when I suggested to `docker run` your `my-apache` yourself (with the right volume attached to the right path)

Comment: hm Ok so then that means it is not possible to do it the gitlab standard-way via `services` directly? Thanks for the patience btw. :-)

Comment: @lockdoc That or I did not understand yet the right way to declare it. Isn't it possible to declare `my-apache` in `gitlab-ci.yml` the same way you declare `my-deploy`? That way, it could benefit from the `config.toml` `runners.docker/volumes` section.

Comment: `.gitlab-ci.yml` is the per project configuration file inside git of each project. The only way I can add additional docker there is to use services. This works fine for a `mysql` service for example, as i can talk to it over tcp 3306. But I don't see any other way to include it into the `.gitlab-ci.yml` file.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative, you could configure your custom apache container to read the files to serve from the /builds/*group*/*project* directory. That seems to work without extra configuration.
You might want to check the blog post I wrote about this: [Running apache and php-fpm as services in a gitlab-ci job](https://blog.johanv.org/posts/php-ci-demo/).